# Not able to add worker after successful installation of Website Controller, Management server,Front end server,Publication server and File server

Tags: azure-pack

After successful installation of Windows azure pack I am trying to install Windows Azure Pack: Web Sites v2 U6.

I am able to install most of the servers to the Website controller. All below servers are in ready state so there is no issue of installation error.

- Management server
- Front end server
- Publication server
- File server.

but while adding Worker server, it's added perfectly and start the installation process. At stage when it reach at the installation it seems like it is not getting some connection string. The information is below.

- Start service: rsfilter.
- Service rsfilter is running.
- Configure Idle Pageout feature.
- Completed configuration of Idle Pageout feature.
- Take ownership for file C:\Windows\system32\Drivers\http.sys.
- Configure DWAS Files location to path 'C:\DWASFiles'
- File caching is turned off
- Execute command 'powershell.exe Import-Module NetQoS; $policy = Get-NetQosPolicy -PolicyStore ActiveStore | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'udplimit' }; if (!$policy) { New-NetQosPolicy -name 'udplimit' -ThrottleRateActionBitsPerSecond 65536 -IpProtocol UDP -PolicyStore ActiveStore -ea Stop }'
- Setup database connection string for server WAPSQL .
- Setup data service credentials.
- Stop service: WAS.
- Service 'WAS' is stopped.
- Set IPv4 dynamic port range, with starting port 30000, and  number of ports 35536.
- Execute command 'netsh.exe int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=30000 num=35536'
- Start service: dwassvc.
- Service dwassvc is running.
- WorkerManagementService started. Ready to receive ConnectionString and DataServiceCredentials.
- Waiting for worker connection string. Attempt number is 12.
- Waiting for worker connection string. Attempt number is 24.
- Waiting for worker connection string. Attempt number is 36.
- Waiting for worker connection string. Attempt number is 48.

I also tried to repair Frontend server as mention in on Microsoft forum but it will not help.

Here's [Microsoft forum link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/dbe70d54-3e44-4c9e-8a2d-8bda4e6492fa/cannot-add-web-worker-back-cannot-connect-to-database?forum=windowsazurepack)

Any trick or guideline will be appreciated

Thanks,

Dharmendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that my Front end server is not accessible from management server and web site controller. It is DNS server that not resolving named correctly (Accessed by IP address but not accessed by server name). Also by using klist tickets I have fount that front end server doesn't have Kerberos ticket available on the list.

For the solution what I have done is, I removed front end server from Web site controller and after that I remove it from Domain controller. Then I rejoin it again to domain. After that I tried it to access it by using it's name from management server and website controller. For example,\FRONTEND\C$.  Then I  first added FrontEnd server and then Web Worker Server and now it get's connection string properly and added with "Ready" status.

Hope this will help someone.

Thanks you very much for point out. It is hectic from more then a week.

Regards,
Dharmendra

Comment: Thanks to Joaquin from Microsoft forum for pointing out. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac7e8a58-adeb-4b58-b259-0b3f164ea1a0/not-able-to-add-worker-after-successful-installation-of-website-controller-management-serverfront?forum=windowsazurepack